# Why can't I use midje to mock a function that throws using slingshot's throw+

Tags: unit-testing, exception, clojure, mocking, midje

Here's the situation: I'm trying to unit test function A that calls function B. Function B is called in a slingshot try+ block and under certain circumstances it can throw using a slingshot throw+. I want to mock function B in a midje test so that it returns something that the catch in the try+ block will actually catch. I can't seem to create the right thing to throw though. Here's a substantially abbreviated sketch of the code and the test:

```
(defn function-A
  [param]
  (try+
    (function-B param)
    (catch [:type :user-not-found]
      (do-something))))

(defn function-B
  [param]
  (throw+ [:type :user-not-found]))

(fact "do-something is called"
  (function-A "param") => (whatever is the result of calling do-something)
  (provided
    (function-B "param") =throws=> (clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo. "throw+: {:type :user-not-found}"
                                                                {:object {:type :user-not-found}, :environment {}}
                                                                nil)))
```

The ExceptionInfo that I'm throwing seems to be roughtly the right thing. I can see this when my application is running through numerous prn statements. However, whatever I try, I can't get the test to work.

I also tried the bit of code below in a repl to see whether I could understand the problem. However, whilst both pieces of code seem to involve identical Exceptions, only one (the pure slingshot one) manages to catch and print "caught it". I think that if I could understand why one works and the other doesn't, I would be able to solve the problem with the unit test.

```
(try+
  (try
    (throw+ {:type :user-not-found})
    (catch Exception e
      (prn "Caught:  " e)
      (prn "Class:   " (.getClass e))
      (prn "Message: " (.getMessage e))
      (prn "Cause:   " (.getCause e))
      (prn "Data:    " (.getData e))
      (throw e)))
  (catch [:type :user-not-found] p
    (prn "caught it")))

(try+
  (try
    (throw (clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo. "throw+: {:type :user-not-found}"
                                        {:object {:type :user-not-found}, :environment {}}
                                        nil))
    (catch Exception e
      (prn "Caught:  " e)
      (prn "Class:   " (.getClass e))
      (prn "Message: " (.getMessage e))
      (prn "Cause:   " (.getCause e))
      (prn "Data:    " (.getData e))
      (throw e)))
  (catch [:type :user-not-found] p
    (prn "caught it")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following slingshot's code for how it generated a throwable (see [here](https://github.com/scgilardi/slingshot/blob/master/src/slingshot/slingshot.clj#L83), [here](https://github.com/scgilardi/slingshot/blob/master/src/slingshot/slingshot.clj#L83) and [here](https://github.com/scgilardi/slingshot/blob/master/src/slingshot/support.clj#L208)), I found the following (somewhat contrived) way for generating a throwable that would work when just `throw`ing.

```
(s/get-throwable (s/make-context {:type :user-not-found} "throw+: {:type :user-not-found}" (s/stack-trace) {}))
```

Which renders the result you were expecting from your example.

```
(try+
  (try
    (throw (s/get-throwable (s/make-context {:type :user-not-found} "throw+: {:type :user-not-found}" (s/stack-trace) {})))
    (catch Exception e
      (prn "Caught:  " e)
      (prn "Class:   " (.getClass e))
      (prn "Message: " (.getMessage e))
      (prn "Cause:   " (.getCause e))
      (prn "Data:    " (.getData e))
      (throw e)))
  (catch [:type :user-not-found] p
    (prn "caught it")))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's brilliant. It certainly works. In my unit test code, I just created a function allowing me to say `=throws=> (slingshot-exception {:type :user-not-found}`. The function is: `(defn slingshot-exception [exception-map] (slingshot.support/get-throwable (slingshot.support/make-context exception-map (str "throw+: " map) (slingshot.support/stack-trace) {})))`. Many thanks for solving my problem.

Answer (score 4):

That's a really late response but what about the following solution:

```
(defn ex+ [cause]
  (try
    (throw+ cause)
    (catch Throwable ex
      ex)))
```

Usage example:

```
(broken-fn) =throws=> (ex+ {:type :user-not-found})
```

The benefit is that you don't rely on internal implementation of Slingshot.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simple and robust, because it relies on the main slingshot API.